# Boost ASIO: Handling synchronous and asynchronous operations in the same class using the same io_context

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I'm trying to write a class using Boost ASIO that can create a TCP connection, send and receive data. It should be able to perform all of those operations via method calls asynchronously as well as synchronously (blocking) with a timeout. My goal is to never have the user interact with ASIO whatsoever, including creating an `io_context` object.

It currently looks approximately like this (without send/receive methods):

```
class TCPClient {
public:
    TCPClient() {
        deadline_.expires_from_now(std::chrono::duration<int>::max());
        check_deadline();
    }

    // --- Callbacks ---
    using ConnectCallback = std::function<void()>;

    // Synchronous and asynchronous
    auto connect(const std::string& host, int port, int timeout=0) -> void;
    auto connect_async(const std::string& host, int port, ConnectCallback callback) -> void;

    auto close() -> void {
        if(socket_) {
            boost::system::error_code ignored_ec;
            socket_->close(ignored_ec);
        }
    }

private:

    /**
     * Adapted from https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/blocking_tcp_client.cpp
     * Replaced deadline_timer with steady_timer to make it compatible with std::chrono
    */
    auto check_deadline() -> void {
        // Close socket if the timer has expired
        if(deadline_.expires_at() <= std::chrono::steady_clock::now()) {
            close();
            deadline_.expires_from_now(std::chrono::duration<int>::max());
        }

        deadline_.async_wait( [this](const auto& ec) {
            check_deadline();
        });
    }

    auto socket() -> tcp::socket& {
        // Create socket if it doesn't exist
        if(!socket_) {
            socket_ = std::make_unique<tcp::socket>(io_);
        }

        // Open interface 
        if(!socket_->is_open()) {
            socket_->open(tcp::v4());
        }
        return *socket_;
    }

    boost::asio::io_context io_;
    std::unique_ptr<tcp::socket> socket_;
    boost::asio::steady_timer deadline_;
};
```

Using the deadline concept [provided by the documentation of ASIO](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/blocking_tcp_client.cpp) I managed to get the synchronous blocking connect method to work:

```
auto TCPClient::connect(const std::string& host, int port, int timeout) -> void {
    // Resolve remote endpoint
    auto query = tcp::resolver::query(host, std::to_string(port));
    auto iter = tcp::resolver(io_).resolve(query);

    // setup deadline
    if(timeout) deadline_.expires_from_now(std::chrono::seconds(timeout));

    // start asynchronous connection
    boost::system::error_code ec = net::error::would_block;     // Never a valid error code if async operation fails
    socket().async_connect( iter->endpoint(), [&ec](const auto& e) {
        ec = e;
    });

    do {
        io_.run_one();
    } while(ec == net::error::would_block);

    if(ec || !socket().is_open()) {
        throw SocketException( get_error_message(ec) );
    }
}
```

As you can see the blocking version of this method does use asynchronous operations under the hood. The waiting is done by calling `io_context.run_one()` repeatedly. Now here's my question: What's the best approach to implementing the connect_async method? I thought about starting a thread performing `io_context.run()` each time an asynchronous operation is called, but I don't seem to get it to work and I think there could be problems if I call synchronous and asynchronous methods together. Or should I maybe toss this approach out of the window and create separate classes for blocking/non blocking operations? As all communication should pass through the same socket, separate `io_context` objects wouldn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `io_context::run()` with `io_context::stop()` and `io_context::restart()` repeatedly. However, I would not recommend it.

In fact, I recommend **not** tying the IO object to an execution context at all, instead accepting an executor object. That way, multiple `TCPClient` will be able to share resources and the service thread.

I mid-way point might be for each `TPCClient` to contain an `io_context` instance and a worker thread. For that to work, you need a work-guard to avoid the thread running out of work prematurely.

> Depending of what approach you use, you may need to avoid a data-race in `check_deadline` by synchronizing access to the object's state. As long as there's only a single service thread and `check_deadline` is only called from the completion handler it is already safe.

### Review Of `connect()`:

- You are not applying the timeout to DNS resolution. This seems like it is probably not intentional
- You are only using the first endpoint from the resolver results. This is also probably not what you want. Use `asio::async_connect` instead
- `check_deadline` is called unconditionally, even when the timer is merely canceled. Also, the timer is not canceled on successful completion. You need to check for timer cancellation
- You're translating error codes, I can't see how, but make sure you use error_condition instead of comparing error codes. Also, consider just using `error_code::message`.
- You're using `would_block` as a stand-in. Consider just `error_code{}` which has conditional conversion to `bool`. Or indeed use `optional<error_code>` for expressive code
- You're using dynamica allocation for the socket_. It's unclear why.

Keeping with your current `io_context` setup, I'd simplify and fix all of the above by writing the operation to be self-contained:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class TCPClient {
  public:
    using error_code      = boost::system::error_code;
    using ConnectCallback = std::function<void()>;

    // Synchronous and asynchronous
    void connect(std::string const& host, int port, int timeout = 0);
    void connect_async(std::string const& host, int port, ConnectCallback callback);

  private:
    asio::io_context io_;
    tcp::socket      socket_{io_};
};

void TCPClient::connect(std::string const& host, int port, int timeout) {
    if (io_.stopped())
        io_.restart();

    error_code    result;
    tcp::resolver resolver{io_};

    // setup optional deadline
    asio::steady_timer deadline{io_, std::chrono::seconds(timeout)};
    if (timeout)
        deadline.async_wait([&](error_code ec) { if (!ec) socket_.cancel(); });

    // resolve and connect under timer
    socket_ = tcp::socket(io_);
    resolver.async_resolve(host, std::to_string(port), [&](error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type eps) {
        if (!(result = ec)) {
            asio::async_connect(socket_, eps, [&](error_code ec, tcp::endpoint) {
                if (!(result = ec))
                    deadline.cancel();
            });
        }
    });

    io_.run();

    if (result.failed() || !socket_.is_open())
        // throw SocketException(result.message());
        throw boost::system::system_error(result);
}

int main() {
    TCPClient c;
    c.connect("localhost", 8989, 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! You're right, having the operation self contained feels more elegant, the `uniqe_ptr` was unnecessary as well.